# Recall chapter title after plates

Tags: floats, sectioning, header-footer

I'd like to generate a catalogue of objects; after each section of the catalogue I'd like to print the plates which show those objects. However, printing the plates with the `plates` package means the running chapter title is changed permanently to *plates*. How can I easily get it back to *catalogue*?

```
\documentclass{thesis}

\usepackage{plates}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Catalogue}

\blindtext
\newpage 

\subsection{Items of Type A}

\blinddescription

\begin{plate}
\caption{Plate caption.}
\label{Plate:1}
\end{plate}

\ProcessPlates
\cleardoublepage

\subsection{Items of Type B}

\blinddescription

\begin{plate}
\caption{Plate caption.}
\label{Plate:1}
\end{plate}

\ProcessPlates
\cleardoublepage




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines in your preamble, so that `plates` doesn't redefine the headings.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\processplates}
  {\markboth{\uppercase{\platesection}}{\uppercase{\platesection}}}
  {\relax}
  {}
  {}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{thesis}

\usepackage{plates}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\processplates}
  {\markboth{\uppercase{\platesection}}{\uppercase{\platesection}}}
  {\relax}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Catalogue}

\blindtext
\newpage

\subsection{Items of Type A}

\blinddescription

\begin{plate}
\caption{Plate 1 caption.}
\label{Plate:1}
\end{plate}

\ProcessPlates
\cleardoublepage

\subsection{Items of Type B}

\blinddescription

\begin{plate}
\caption{Plate 2 caption.}
\label{Plate:2}
\end{plate}

\ProcessPlates
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Works perfectly.

Comment: @marcellinus12 You're welcome.

Comment: @marcellinus12 BTW, since it works perfectly, any reason for not accepting it?